# How to calculate the percent change of a data frame column, then the next, and so on?

Tags: r

I have the below data-frame, call it "p":

```
    Q1  Q2  Q3
X Product   4.986184956 5.083868356 5.109861156
Y Product   2.86990877  2.834816682 2.904347607
Z Product   6.58413545  6.238497279 6.40142101
```

I would like to calculate the percent change between each of the columns in p, and place the output for each column into a new data-frame called "pchange".

I've tried using the lag() function, but I haven't been successful with it. (I'm still quite new with the language.)

I really appreciate any thoughts on how best to tackle this. Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question with your expected output.

Comment: Are you interested in row-wise or column-wise change? Seems like you'd be interested in in change from one quarter to another. In that case, if you don't need a programmatic solution (something that can do this for more than these three quarters), you might try 
`pchange <- df %>% 
  transmute(
    change_Q1_Q2 = ((Q2 - Q1)/Q1)*100,
    change_Q2_Q3 = ((Q3 - Q2)/Q2)*100
  )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few different approaches.  No packages are used.

**1)** Divide all but the first 2 columns by all but the first and last columns, subtract 1 and multiply by 100.  Combine that with the original first column and NA times the original second column.

```
data.frame(DF[1], NA * DF[2], 100 * (DF[-(1:2)] / DF[-c(1, ncol(DF))] - 1))
```

giving:

```
    Product Q1        Q2       Q3
1 X Product NA  1.959081 0.511280
2 Y Product NA -1.222760 2.452749
3 Z Product NA -5.249560 2.611586
```

**1a)**  A variation of (1) that is even shorter is based on working in the log domain and then converting back:

```
data.frame(DF[1], NA * DF[2], 100 * t(exp(diff(t(log(DF[-1]))))-1))
```

giving:

```
    Product Q1        Q2       Q3
1 X Product NA  1.959081 0.511280
2 Y Product NA -1.222760 2.452749
3 Z Product NA -5.249560 2.611586
```

**2)** Define a function `percent` which calculates the percentages based on vector `x` returning a vector the same length as `x` filling in the first element with NA since there is no prior value for which to calculate its percent.  Then apply that to each row noting that `apply` will return the transpose of what we want so transpose it back.

```
percent <- function(x) 100 * c(NA * x[1], diff(x) / head(x, -1))
data.frame(DF[1], t(apply(DF[-1], 1, percent)))
```

giving:

```
    Product Q1        Q2       Q3
1 X Product NA  1.959081 0.511280
2 Y Product NA -1.222760 2.452749
3 Z Product NA -5.249560 2.611586
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form was assumed to be:

```
DF <- structure(list(Product = structure(1:3, .Label = c("X Product", 
"Y Product", "Z Product"), class = "factor"), Q1 = c(4.986184956, 
2.86990877, 6.58413545), Q2 = c(5.083868356, 2.834816682, 6.238497279
), Q3 = c(5.109861156, 2.904347607, 6.40142101)), .Names = c("Product", 
"Q1", "Q2", "Q3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful, and lots of good suggestions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Copying from my above comment. Simple solution using `dplyr::transmute:`

```
pchange <- df %>% 
  transmute(
    change_Q1_Q2 = ((Q2 - Q1)/Q1)*100,
    change_Q2_Q3 = ((Q3 - Q2)/Q2)*100
  )
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  change_Q1_Q2 change_Q2_Q3
         <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1.959081     0.511280
2    -1.222760     2.452749
3    -5.249560     2.611586
```

If you wanted to keep the Product column you could use `mutate` instead of `transmute`. I'd echo Jens Leerssen's endorsement of R for Data Science.

(Assuming your data is structured like so)

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
~Product, ~Q1,  ~Q2,  ~Q3,
"X Product", 4.986184956, 5.083868356, 5.109861156,
"Y Product",   2.86990877,  2.834816682, 2.904347607,
"Z Product",   6.58413545,  6.238497279, 6.40142101)
```

Answer (score 2):

A clean and readily extensible solution can be most easily achieved by tidying up your dataframe. The subject can get complicated, but essentialy just make it so each row is a single observation and each column is one variable.

While Constructing direct references between your columns may get you a quick win, if you start adding more columns you will be forced to write more code. With Tidy data, you will not. The tidy solutions will handle the updating data without further hiccups.

Using a rebuild of your view of your dataframe: `p`

```
library(tidyverse)
id <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
object <- "Product"
Q1 <- c(4.986184956, 2.86990877, 6.58413545)
Q2 <- c(5.083868356, 2.834816682, 6.238497279)
Q3 <- c(5.109861156, 2.904347607, 6.40142101)
p <- tibble(id, object, Q1, Q2, Q3)
```

> ```
> > p
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
>      id  object       Q1       Q2       Q3
>   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1     X Product 4.986185 5.083868 5.109861
> 2     Y Product 2.869909 2.834817 2.904348
> 3     Z Product 6.584135 6.238497 6.401421
> ```

You can then execute the transform in *tidyverse* as below:

```
tidy_p_change <- 
    p %>% 
    gather(qrtr, perf, c(Q1:Q3)) %>% # tidy the data
    arrange(id, qrtr) %>%  # prep for lag (and easy auditing)
    group_by(id) %>%  # keep the lags within products
    mutate(prev_q = lag(perf),  # bring data together into same row
           pct_chng = (perf/prev_q - 1)*100 
           ) %>%
    select(-c(perf, prev_q)) %>% # stop showing the work 
    spread(qrtr, pct_chng) # spread the data back out into a `pivot table`
```

Which will give you this output:

> ```
> > tidy_p_change
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
> # Groups:   id [3]
>      id  object    Q1        Q2       Q3
> * <chr>   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1     X Product    NA  1.959081 0.511280
> 2     Y Product    NA -1.222760 2.452749
> 3     Z Product    NA -5.249560 2.611586
> ```

I have left the wrangling in its verbose form. I can spool the wire down tighter, but thought it best to show all the steps. Let us know if you would like to see a more bummed down version, too.

Additionally, a really great treatment about working with tidy data (and working in tidyverse) can be found in Hadley Wickham's [*R for Data Science*](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll look into tidy for future examples.